# SetIntervale inside a for loop (arrays) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, setinterval

I'm drawing a rectangle one by one in setIntervale,the variable `entra` is the number of rectangles that should draw. I get this number from the Array `entradas[]`, which position of the Array corresponds to which row from the data base.
That is the effect that I have when I put without the loop: http://gyazo.com/0b84f082c4518c7c42a1651173e7b961
But when I put inside of `for`, it draws 5 rectangles at same time. Like this: http://gyazo.com/ae572457a6e1a23f984aa2ae0984d77e

I want to draw which row at a time, and which rectangle of a row at a time. What is wrong?

```
for (var li=1; li < linhas; li++) {
    //var li=1;
    (function (li) {
        setInterval ( function () {
            if (categoria[li]) {
                entra=entradas[li];
                tex=texturas[li];
            }

            if (rects<entra) {
                World.add(_world, Bodies.rectangle( Math.round(Common.random(300,400)),-20,Math.round(Common.random(20,30)),Math.round(Common.random(20,30)), { render: { strokeStyle: '#ffffff',  sprite: { texture: tex } } } ));
            }
        }, 500);

        contagem = setInterval( function(){
            if(rects<entra){
                rects=rects+1;
                document.getElementById("mytext").value = rects;
                rectsmoney=rects*valor[1];
                document.getElementById("mytext2").value = Math.round(rectsmoney);
            } 
        }, 500);

        if (rects >= entra) {
            rects=0;
            li++;
        }
    }) (li);
}
```

Comment: And what do you expect it to do? If you use a for loop, all will happen at once. You may want to use recursion to draw things "one at a time".

Comment: @Cristy I know that it doesn't make sense, but I didn't know other way. How recursion is used?

Comment: Create a function, let's call it `func` where you add the box (or whatever you do in your for) that accepts a parameter `count` that stores how many iterations there are left. Then at the end of that function, if count is larger than zero you do `setTimeout(function(){ func(count-1)}, 500);`. This will call again the function after 500ms. This is the way to do a `for` that contains async stuff.